# How to Disable/Enable an Ajax toolkit Tabcontainer using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have used a tab container in ajax toolkit.
How can I Enable/Disable tabs using jquery??
I know following code for setting tab index but what about enabling/Disabling a specified tab?

```
var ctrl = $find(TabControl);
ctrl.set_activeTabIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$find(TabControl).get_tabs()[1].set_enabled(false);
```